# Angular 2 Promise throw error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services

I am trying to make a service that handles contacts in Angular 2. This is what i got so far.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class ContactsService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  addContact(contact): Promise<any> {
    return this.http
      .post('http://localhost:8000/contacts', contact)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(error => error.json());
  }
}
```

Now the service works fine, if i get a `400+` status code on the response, the code goes to the `catch` stare, if it's `200` code it goes to `then` state and returns the response.

But when i use it inside a component, it goes to `then` state no matter if the respone is ok or not.

```
addingContact() {
  this.contactsService
    .addContact(this.user)
    .then(
      (contactx) => { console.log('THEN = ' + JSON.stringify(contactx)); },
      (err) => { console.log('CATCH = ' + JSON.stringify(err)); }
    );
}
```

Is there something i'm missing, should i throw something on the service so the code goes to the error start incase i get a `400+` status code ?

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Comment: In fact, your code above solved my problem :). Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are swallow the error in catch, you can still have a catch clause to transform the error but you need to return a rejected Promise from it. Something like that:

```
  let httpPromiseMock  = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
    reject('400 error');
  });

 httpPromiseMock
 .then(x=> {console.log(x); return x*2;})
 .catch(x=> Promise.reject(`my error is ${x}`))
 .then(x=>console.log('good',x), 
    err=>console.log('bad', err));
```

Comment: modified the service to .catch(error => Promise.reject(error.json())) and it works exactly as i expected it to work, thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

> Should i throw something on the service so the code goes to the error start in case i get a 400+ status code?

Yes, because right now, your `catch` statement of the service is swallowing the error.

You could also get rid of the `catch` statement there, but you'll have to remember to add one in every piece of code that uses `addContact`.

Comment: thank you, i understand now what i did wrong, i still resolve it even in the catch state that's probably why it doesnt return an error in the component, fixed it tho with Promise.reject